Sonic MQ 12.0 not able to connect with Spring Boot 3.3.1 version
While creating ConnectionFactory by using TopicConnectionFactory with the latest version of spring boot 3.3.1, facing issue like jakarta package is expected by progress.message.jclient.TopicConnectionFactory which is not available currently.
Tried with setting up the TopicConnectionFactory with Spring-stater-jms with latest version not able to fetch Sonic Client, Looking for the Listener Setup with Spring boot 3 & jakarta

Spring Boot 3 only supports the Jakarta namespace which means you can't use anything in the javax namespace (e.g. javax.jms.*). Therefore, you'll need to get a client implementation from SonicMQ that supports the Jakarta namespace.

By Using Eclispe transformer we are use with latest version of spring boot 3.3.1
https://github.com/eclipse/transformer/tree/1.0.0
This is the stable verison and worked as expected.
It is very powerful it can migrate even the .class files.and complete steps are provided in the documentation section.
Reference Blog
https://medium.com/@nageshwarrao.addanki87/sonic-mq-12-0-upgrade-with-jakarta-namespace-to-use-spring-boot-3-0-694ee21817f9
